# Kivy Buildozer python3 error: " ImportError: No module named 'requests' "

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm trying to build a simple kivy app with buildozer and python3, but for some reason inside this build no module 'requests'. I have tried to manually include this module as "required" for build in python, but this caused the error as far as 'requests" is already included in python3. I'm not sure on which side this problem is: buildozer or python-for-android.

Source:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
import requests

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text='Hello!',
              font_size=150)

        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)
        return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Log from logcat:

09-19 16:50:50.429 14737 14756 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

09-19 16:50:50.442 14737 14756 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):

09-19 16:50:50.442 14737 14756 I python  :    File "main.py", line 5, in

09-19 16:50:50.444 14737 14756 I python  :      import requests

09-19 16:50:50.444 14737 14756 I python  :  ImportError: No module named 'requests'

09-19 16:50:50.508 14737 14756 I python  : Python for android ended.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and I can not compile with requests if I add it in the requirements. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: requests module is not included in python3, you have to provide it in requirements

Comment: If you are compiling for android, you may need to add the dependencies for `requests`. I had to add: `certifi, chardet, urllib3, idna, requests` in the requirements line in `buildozer.spec`. You can find the dependencies for modules by doing `pip show your-module`

Comment: Hi, Have you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

just add the following directory to the project

charset_normalizer,
idna,
urllib3,
requests,

it work for me